# Get back to default zsh theme in kali linux

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I tried to change the default `zsh` theme with `oh-my-zsh` from their [github repository](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes) and I just edited `.zshrc` switching from the default theme to another one and it just somehow went wrong cause now I can't switch anymore and the theme stays the same even tho I'm switching to new ones.

I just wanna go back to the regular out of the box `zsh` theme that's in Kali. Can someone help me? (I'd prefer the easy way cause I'm not an adavnced linux user, yet). Thanks a lot!

[image: Here's a pic:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not an advanced user, beware that Kali does a whole load of things differently to usual. This is because it's targeted at experienced security professionals. That said, you should be able to get a fresh copy of `.zshrc` from the template directory `/etc/skel`