# What ZSH theme does Kali use?

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, oh-my-zsh

Could someone please give me the name of the default ZSH theme that Kali uses? Also, if you could please provide a link to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get back to default zsh theme in kali linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616723/get-back-to-default-zsh-theme-in-kali-linux)

Comment: nope I want the theme for other Linux distros sorry for not specifying that

Comment: Bira is close but it's not the same, [Fox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655096/what-zsh-theme-does-kali-use) is the theme Kali uses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kali Linux does not use a separate theme file for its zsh customizations. So you cannot download the Kali Linux zsh theme, drop it in `themes/`, and set `ZSH_THEME` to its name as [you usually can in Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes). Instead, the customizations are made to `.zshrc` directly. You can inspect [`.zshrc` which is included into Kali Linux](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/kali-defaults/-/blob/kali/master/etc/skel/.zshrc) and choose what customizations you want.

Be careful to keep a backup of your existing `~/.zshrc`. I also used `zsh -d -f; source /path/to/file` as [suggested and explained in another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131717/423679) to test the configurations without replacing the existing configuration file at all.

Here is some further reading:

- [Kali Linux zsh for macos](https://statropy.com/blog/kali-linux-zsh-for-macos/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the Bira theme is pretty similar in terms of appearance to Kali.

See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes#bira